# Can't hide <include> item programmaticaly

Tags: android, android-viewbinding

Android Studio 3.6

in app/build.gradle:

```
android {
viewBinding.enabled = true
```

In my activity:

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = QrBluetoothSwipeActivityBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
}
```

in my `qr_bluetooth_swipe_activity.xml`

```
      <include
            android:id="@+id/blueToothBottonContainer"
            layout="@layout/bluetooth_bottom_container"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

I want to hide **blueToothBottonContainer** programmaticaly.
So I try this:

```
private fun setBottomContainreViewMode(isQrScreenVisible: Boolean) {
        if (isQrScreenVisible) {
            binding.qrBottonContainer.
        }
}
```

but not found method smt like `setVisible`

why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[setVisibility](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)) method belongs to a View class. `<include>` tag is not really a `layout(View + ViewGroups)`. That's why you won't find `setVisibility` method on it.

To hide the included layout, you can give id to parent layout in your `bluetooth_bottom_container` layout and then change it's visiblity from `binding.blueToothBottonContainer.{parent_layout_id}`.